# Parameter estimation in a heteroscedastic model

Tags: estimation, heteroscedasticity, generalized-least-squares

Consider the following model:
$$Y = \mu + (1+\beta X)\epsilon,$$
where $Y$ is the dependent variable; $X$ is the independent variable; $\epsilon$ is such that $\mathbb{E}(\epsilon) = 0$ and $\mathbb{V}(\epsilon) = 1$; and $(\mu,\beta)$ is the parameters vector.

I wonder if anyone would have a suggestion for a estimation procedure for the parameter vector.

You can assume that $X$ and $\epsilon$ are independent (or any other assumption you find necessary).

Comment: By WN (presumably "white noise") do you mean independent Gaussian noise or something else? Note that you can have [white noise that's not Gaussian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_noise#Statistical_properties)

Comment: By $WN(0,1)$ I mean a sequence of uncorrelated random variables with zero mean and constant variance equal to one. But I would have no problems with solutions that make more assumptions.

Comment: Thanks. It would be useful to include that additional clarification in your post.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem using numerical methods by applying MCMC sampler.

Or if you can design your experiments,

- set $X$ to zero, record data sample, then estimate  $\mu$ using LS;
- set $X$ to 1, record other data sample, then $Var(Y) = \sqrt{1+\beta}$ .